# Monte Carlo pi method with fixed x

Tags: algorithm, random, montecarlo, pi

In all Monte Carlo example codes I have found which calculate pi, both x and y are generated randomly between 0 and 1. For example, an example code looks like

```
  Ran rdm(time(NULL));
  double x, y;
  int sum=0;
  for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
  {
    x=rdm.doub();         // Both x and y are generated randomly
    y=rdm.doub();
    if(x*x+y*y<1)
      sum++;
  }
  return 4.*sum/N;
```

I don't understand what is the point to randomly generate both axis rather than choose a fixed and uniform x list and then only generate y randomly, like an example code below.

```
  Ran rdm(time(NULL));
  double x=0.5/N, dx=1./N, y;   //x is a fixed sequential list
  int sum=0;
  for(int i=0;i<N;i++)
  {
    y=rdm.doub();               // only y is generated randomly
    if(x*x+y*y<1)
      sum++;
    x+=dx;
  }
  return 4.*sum/N;
```

I tried both examples. Both methods converge with speed ~ 1/sqrt(N). The error of the second method is slightly smaller and the second code runs slightly faster.  So it seems to me that the second method is better. And for sampling in higher dimension space, I think one can always pick a fixed list in one dimension and randomly sampling in other dimensions. Is this true?

Is there any reference that can prove the fixed x method is also correct?

If the fixed x method is better, why I have never seen any example code written in this way? Is it related to the adaptive importance sampling?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe it will work even if both x and y are generated uniformly. In that case, you'd be laying out a uniform grid of points and seeing which ones fall inside the circle.

I think you are right that for a given number of points, the uniform sampling would be as accurate as the random sampling, but significantly faster.

But what if you don't know the number of points you should use? In this case, I think the random sampling is better, because you can keep adding points until the overall value changes very little. You can't simply increment the number of points if you're using a uniform distribution. Any time you increase the number of points, you have to create an entire grid.

Comment: I think the uniform sampling in all dimension is much slower in multi-dimension problem.  For example, in 3D, uniformly sampling converge with speed of N^{1/3}, slower than completely random sampling, which is N^{1/2}.  
And if only uniform sampling in one direction, I don't think you have to do everything all over again. You only need to uniformly sample the increased number of points.

Comment: Inspired by your answer, I think there is a problem for the uniform sampling method (in 1D) if the function is not smooth.  This method only samples on the grid center.  If the function changes significantly in a grid zone, the result can be unreliable.  This may indicate that the converging speed of this method depends on the feature of the integrand function.

Comment: @HD189733b Isn't N^{1/3} faster? I can't see how a random distribution would be better. If I wanted to calculate the volume of a sphere, and I had exactly 1,000 points to do it, I would think a uniform distribution of points would be optimal - and never worse than 1,000 random points. Think about it: how would you improve the uniform grid? Anything non-uniform would have a biases in certain locations.

Comment: @HD189733b Agreed, uniform sampling would be problematic for non-smooth functions.

Comment: Yes, you are right. I made a mistake. The convergence speed for uniformly sampling is not N^{-1/3}, but faster than N^{-1/2}, at lease for the case of smooth function.

Answer (score 0):

Your method for computing π is indeed valid. I'm sure math.SE would give you a crisp proof of this, but it's basically (1) the unit disk is Riemann integrable (2) the indicator variable for each slice has the right expectation (3) Hoeffding's inequality (e.g.) to show convergence in probability for the sum.

Thing is, this method doesn't work on sets that are not Riemann integrable. Consider, for instance, the set ([0, 1] - **Q**) × ([0, 1] - **Q**), which has measure 1 but on which your method will always sample the rational x columns, which are not in the set.

See also [low-discrepancy sequences](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Low-discrepancy_sequence), which is your idea taken a step further.

Comment: Thank you! Could you please comment on the convergence speed? Can I say fully equally spaced sequence is an extreme case of low-discrepancy sequences? So what I did is actually an extreme case of quasi-Monte Carlo method, is it true?

Comment: After some search, I don't find any reference of low-discrepancy sequence or quasi-monte carlo method discussed about the equally spaced sequence.  So I'm afraid it's incorrect to make that statement.